# How to deal with suspicions of neighbours abusing animals

Tags: dogs, tortoises

I'm from the UK and my next-door neighbour keeps 2 dogs and a tortoise in a tiny little house. I have lived in this house for five years and have never seen her walk her dogs once and they constantly bark and howl. The tortoise is a recently addition to the house of heck and the clown has put the tortoise right next to my back garden fence.

I have a dog myself and he is trying to rip through the fence constantly to reach the tortoise as it is annoying him. I don't think she is competent to keep pets as the current arrangement is not good for my dog who is constantly stressed or her tortoise who I'm concerned may be hurt.

We are not on speaking terms so I would be interested in any suggestions about how to deal with this problem. This woman shouldn't be allowed to keep pets and if I have any legal ground I would like to contact the RSPCA.

Comment: Why haven't you contacted the RSPCA?

Comment: Because the dogs seem healthy when I've seen them, it's just that they're never walked and the tortoise has only been there a week or so. I don't know if the behaviour I've described is legally classified as abuse even though I definitely find it abusive.

Answer (score 4):

If you think an animal is mistreated you have to alert the RSPCA and the police, they might not act at once but one needs to keep telling them about it and try to help the animals until they do. If they find that the animals are not mistreated there is not a lot one can do, except keeping an eye on it and alerting the RSPCA and police again until they do something to solve it.

This answer is about all animals, not only pets but farm animals too.

Answer (score 2):

If I were in your shoes, I'd visit her as a neighbour and say like ''Hey what cute dogs'' and ask her if they go out if not I'd ask to walk them myself. That's until the cops or the RSPCA comes to solve the problem. I don't think the tortoise is abused though considering what you say.

Comment: So how are the dogs now?